# How to know expiry of BigCommerce permanent token in advance and renew that

Tags: bigcommerce

When permanent token is received, BigCommerce documentation says that it will expire in 30-60 days.Any idea, how one can know in advance about expiry and how to renew it because I dont see any API call to renew it.

Answer (score 1):

By information from BigCommerce's API support. The token is absolutely permanent.
They have plan to update REST API, including token generation. After that token will have expirency time, and additional endpoint to renew it.